# Factor the binomial $36 m^2 - \frac{25}{4} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

OK, I got a new one... it's $36 m^2 - \frac{25}4 $

and I got:

$(18m-\frac{5}2 )(18m+\frac{5}2 )$ although that is incorrect... where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try taking the square root of $36m^2$ again.

Comment: six times six is thirty-six

Comment: And $18\times18$ is not 36.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are right,since:

$$ 36 m^2 - \frac{25}4 = (6m)^2 - \left(\frac{5}2 \right)^2 = \left(6m + \frac{5}2 \right)\left(6m - \frac{5}2 \right) $$

Comment: Arg... I tried adding instead of multiplying.. thank you.